# Java RecycleView loading image in different pages

Tags: java, android

I am an Android beginner developing a mobile app in Java that will display images that I got from the Imgur API.
To do it I am using a `RecycleView` that is included in two pages, one displaying the main page with popular pictures and another one displaying the account favorite picture.

My problem is that when I load a page, for example the favorite one, and then I change to the menu, the x pictures present in the favorite page will still be displayed **instead** of the menu ones. But when I change back to the favorite page, the images will be those of the menu page.

---

Here is an example of what's happening:

In my first screen I'm on my main page and everything is fine, but when I change to my favorites the pictures are replaced by those in my main page. As you can see only one picture is displayed because I only have one picture as favorite (which isn't this one).

And if I go back to my main page it will display my real picture set as favorite that will replace the "I AM SPEED" one, and then display the other pictures.

[image]
[image]

---

Here is my `RecycleView Fragment`:

```
public class ItemFragmentGallery extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_COLUMN_COUNT = "column-count";
    private int mColumnCount = 1;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    public ItemFragmentGallery() {
    }

    public static ItemFragmentGallery newInstance(int columnCount) {
        ItemFragmentGallery fragment = new ItemFragmentGallery();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT, columnCount);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mColumnCount = getArguments().getInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT);
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(900);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_list, container, false);

        if (view instanceof RecyclerView) {
            Context context = view.getContext();
            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;
            recyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));

            ItemAdapterGallery adapter = new ItemAdapterGallery(GalleryAPI.ITEMS);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            RecycleViewSeparator decoration = new RecycleViewSeparator(view.getContext(), Color.rgb(147, 129, 255), 4f);
            recyclerView.addItemDecoration(decoration);
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

And my `RecycleView Adapter`:

```
    public class ItemAdapterGallery extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapterGallery.ViewHolder> {

    private List<GalleryAPI.DummyItem> mValues;

    public ItemAdapterGallery(List<GalleryAPI.DummyItem> items) {

        mValues = items;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.fragment_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        String avatar = "https://imgur.com/user/" + mValues.get(position).user + "/avatar";
        Picasso.get().load(avatar).transform(new RoundImage(70, 10)).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_baseline_account_circle_24).into(holder.mUserImageView);
        holder.mUserPseudoView.setText("u/" + mValues.get(position).user + " • " + mValues.get(position).datetime);
        holder.mTitleView.setText(mValues.get(position).title);
        holder.mLikesView.setText(mValues.get(position).likes);
        Picasso.get().load(mValues.get(position).url).fit().centerInside().placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).into(holder.mUrlView);
        holder.mUrlView.getLayoutParams().height = Integer.parseInt(mValues.get(position).height);

        holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.download).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new DownloadImage(holder.itemView.getContext()).execute(mValues.get(position).url);
            }
        });
        final SingletonData singleton = SingletonData.getInstance();

        holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.upvote).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (singleton.accessToken.equals(""))
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "You must be connected to perform this action", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else {
                    VoteAPI vote = new VoteAPI();
                    vote.execute("https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/" + mValues.get(position).imageId + "/vote/up", "POST");
                }
            }
        });

        holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.downvote).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (singleton.accessToken.equals(""))
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "You must be connected to perform this action", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else {
                    VoteAPI vote = new VoteAPI();
                    vote.execute("https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/" + mValues.get(position).imageId + "/vote/down", "POST");
                }
            }
        });

        holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.favorite).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (singleton.accessToken.equals(""))
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "You must be connected to perform this action", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else {
                    FavoriteAPI api = new FavoriteAPI(holder.itemView.getContext());
                    api.execute("https://api.imgur.com/3/image/" + mValues.get(position).imageId + "/favorite", "POST");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mValues.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public final View mView;
        public final ImageView mUserImageView;
        public final TextView mTitleView;
        public final TextView mLikesView;
        public final TextView mUserPseudoView;
        public final ImageView mUrlView;
        public GalleryAPI.DummyItem mItem;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mView = view;
            mUserImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.userImage);
            mTitleView = view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            mLikesView = view.findViewById(R.id.likes);
            mUserPseudoView = view.findViewById(R.id.userPseudo);
            mUrlView = view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide screenshots that exemplify the problem? It's hard to tell what exactly you're asking.

Comment: Yes sorry if it might be hard to understand, I've explained it a little more and added two screenshots of my phone.

Comment: Are you using the same instance of the RecyclerView.Adapter for both views?

Comment: In both files I am first making a call to the API to stock values, and then I include my ItemGalleryFragment, so both views have a RecyclerView.Adapter, but not the same instance.
But I think that my problem can come from the API call and the new thread created by it. I use Thread.sleep() because I had a similar issue, no picture was displayed and I had to reload the page to see them.